# Meaning of "work out"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

What does **work out** mean in this sentence?

> Charles Babbage, an English mathematician **worked out** the principles of the modern computer.

Comment: I think this could be a good question, but I think it ought to show some research before it gets reopened. It’s [not that hard to find the meaning of _work out_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/work%20out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasal verb [**to work something out**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-out) (see the first definition) generally refers to the act of solving some sort of problem or finding (or even developing) a solution to a problem. For instance, if I have a mathematical equation and I want you to work out the solution to that equation, what I want you to do is to find that solution using your math skills. Here's an example:

> I was completely unable to **work out** the solution to this very difficult differential equation. Will you help me solve it?

In the case of your example, what Charles Babbage had done was come up with or find or develop the ideas that underlie the principles of the modern computer (whether that's historically true or not is a discussion for another time).